# COUNT query with mysql with condition from one field from table

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following table:

> field1 | field2 | field3
>
> ----3--------5--------6
>
> ----8--------5--------3
>
> ----2--------4--------8

What I'd like to do is **COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field3 = 6 AND...** field2 is the same as the **field2 from the row where field3 = 6  (in this case, '5')**. Is this possible?

In this scope, the result of the count would be **2**

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @Strawberry you have to read it first to understand what the question is actually. If this isn't clear enough, :]

Comment: @ChrisWesseling pretty much never.

Comment: According to the table you have there, the result would be 1, not 2. There is only one row where field3 = 6 and field2 = 5.

Comment: a. You're wrong. b. You're doing nothing to ingratiate yourself to anyone here, and with the attitude you seem to have it's unlikely people are going to want to assist you in the future.

Comment: @user3385828 I think you mean `OR` not `AND`

Comment: Well, there's always one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You can almost turn your problem statement directly into a query:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where field3 = 6 and
      field2 in (select field2 from table2 where field3 = 6);
```

Note the use of `in` instead of `=` in the `where` clause.  This takes into account the case where there are multiple matches in the subquery.

EDIT:

Here is another more confusing query that does the same thing:

```
select count(field3 = 6)
from table t
group by field2
having max(field3 = 6) > 0;
```

I'll leave this as food-for-thought on how it works.

Comment: HAVING really *is* your favourite clause isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling . . . Ironically, in my categorization of SQL things, `having` is in the category of "not needed", along with `select distinct`, `right outer join`, `avg`, and commas in the `from` clause (well, the latter is evil).  It is perfectly expressible with a subquery and `where`, except that some query engines make this difficult.

Comment: where do you get `field3 = 3`, OP has field3 = 6... Which makes the in subselect in the right operand of the AND a tautology and thus it can be eliminated.